# Solving for coefficients in a polynominal

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, constraint, coefficients

I've the following problem:

> how can I solve for the coefficients in a polynominal?

So, I mean the following:

I've the following expression:

$$\left(56-85689\cdot x\right)^2-3136\tag1$$

And I know that I can write:

$$\left(a-bx\right)^2-a^2=-2 a b x + b^2 x^2\tag2$$

Now:

> How can I solve for $-2ab$ and $b^2$ using $(1)$? Without writing out the product using bij $(1) because in a real life example it is not a square but a 9th power or something.

It does not work when I try:

```
Solve[(56 - 85689)^2 - 3136 == -2 a b x + b^2 x^2, {a, b}]
```

Comment: `SolveAlways[(56 - 85689 x)^2 - 3136 == -2 a b x + b^2 x^2, {x}]`

Comment: You left an “x” out of the product 85689 in the Solve. Might not help but the question should be edited. Sent from my iPad

Comment: Do you *actually* want to solve for "$-2ab$" and "$b^2$"?

Comment: The example above appears to use two different values for `a`. Anyway, my guess is `CoefficientList` would be the desired function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Solve[
 CoefficientList[(56 - 85689 x)^2 - 3136, x] == 
  CoefficientList[-2 a b x + b^2 x^2, x], {a, b}]`

`{{a -> -56, b -> -85689}, {a -> 56, b -> 85689}}`